# Quessing game by Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make simple guessing game by object method.I want to practice object method. Everything is working, except one condition. I want compare input with random num. I don't know why this condition ignore me. How can I fix it?  Thank you

```
let game = {  
  quess: () => {
    const input = document.querySelector('.input').value
     return input
  },
  randomNumber: () => {
    //const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    const x = 3   // for testing
    return x
  },
  displayQuess: function() {
      const userNum = document.querySelector('.quess')
      return userNum.innerHTML = this.quess()
  },
 
  clearFields: function() {
    document.querySelector('.input').value = ''
  },
  result: function() {
     const output = document.querySelector('.output')
   
     const input = this.quess()
     const random = this.randomNumber()
     
     
     if(random === input) {         // this condition ignore me , why ? 
       output.innerHTML = ' Winner !!'
     } 

     if(input != random) {
       output.innerHTML = 'correct num was : ' + random
     }
  }
}

 const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
 const output = document.querySelector('.output')
 const quesss = document.querySelector('.quesses')

 let quesses = 3

 btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
   //console.log( game.displayQuess())
      game.displayQuess()
      game.clearFields()
      game.result()

      quesses--
      quesss.innerHTML = quesses
      if(quesses < 1 ){
          output.style.color = 'red'
          output.innerHTML = 'game over'
          document.querySelector('.input').disabled = true;
          document.querySelector('.btn').disabled = true;
      }  
 })
```

Comment: simple, `"3" !== 3` because `this.quess()` returns a **string**, whereas, `this.randomNumber()` returns a **number** - you could `return +input` in `this.quess()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: It still ignore me . I was trying  *return Number(input)  also  if(input == random) {
       output.innerHTML = ' Winner !!'
     }

Comment: You're clearing the input before calling `result`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `===` is a strict type equality check. It checks that both operands are of the same type and are equal. This is not passing the condition because you are comparing a number with a string. Even though they have the same value, they are of data types (a numeric type, and a text (string) type).

You can use `==` to do loose equality checks, which allows checking across different types, but it is better practice to use strict equality checks. So if you expect a number, it might be better to convert the string type to a number type

```
quess: () => {
    const input = document.querySelector('.input').value
     return parseFloat(input);
  },
```

Further Reading:

- [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
- [Strict Equality (===)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)
- [Equality (==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)

Comment: ah.. it's because you are calling `game.clearFields()` fields before you call `result`. So you are clearing the text field before you are reading it to test the win state. If you use the chrome web inspector, you can breakpoint to see the control flow.

Comment: bingo . right now is it working . Thnak you .

Comment: I am not using chrome web inspector, I will check it . Thank you again :)

Comment: Could be safari web inspector, or firefox dev tools. All mainstream browsers have their own web debugging tools ;)